# Is their any way to make "stratio cassandra-lucene-index" query from node js

Tags: node.js, cassandra, lucene, cassandra-lucene-index

I am using "stratio cassandra-lucene-index" plugin for making spatial queries to cassandra below is my query which i am making from cqlsh and is working fine,

```
SELECT * FROM user_location WHERE expr(user_location_index, '{filter:{type:"geo_distance", field:"place", latitude: 28.6076, longitude: 77.3683, max_distance:"20km"}, sort:{field: "place", type: "geo_distance", latitude: 28.6076, longitude: 77.3683}}');
```

*My Question is How can i make this above query from Node.js, I am using cassandra-driver for other queries, Any suggestion is appreciated.*

Answer (score 2):

Since cassandra 3.x, secondary index query syntax changed from:

```
SELECT * from table where lucene='query';
```

to:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE expr(index_name,'query');
```

But no one else has adopted this query type yet (spark-cassandra connector...). So we still allow old style query syntax.

References: [Alternative syntaxes](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.0.8/doc/documentation.rst#alternative-syntaxes)